# Boost Spirit nested components

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to parse the following messages with Spirit Qi:

```
"A/B AND C/D", "A/B", "A/B AND C/D AND E/F"
```

I am able to parse "A/B" but cannot get the correct results for the other strings.

I tried to following code:

```
qi::rule<It, AstNodeVector()> entries;
qi::rule<It, AstNodeVector()> lists;
qi::rule<It, std::string()> element;

this->entries= *(this->lists % " AND ");
this->lists= this->element >> '/' >> this->element;
this->element = qi::char_("A-Z");
```

What is wrong with my grammar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're not skipping whitespace. Maybe that's a conceptual problem (see [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)).

Regardless, it does parse:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/087fe0ddb05d4246)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

using AstNodeVector = std::vector<std::string>;

template <typename It>
struct P : qi::grammar<It, AstNodeVector()> {
    P() : P::base_type(entries) {
        entries = *(lists % " AND ");
        lists   = element >> '/' >> element;
        element = qi::char_("A-Z");
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, AstNodeVector()> entries;
    qi::rule<It, AstNodeVector()> lists;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> element;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    P<It> const p {};

    for (std::string const input: {
        "A/B AND C/D",
        "A/B",
        "A/B AND C/D AND E/F",
        })
    {
        It f = begin(input), l = end(input);
        AstNodeVector results;
        if (phrase_parse(f, l, p, qi::space, results)) {
            std::cout << "Success: " << std::quoted(input) << "\n";
            for (auto& el : results) {
                std::cout << " -- " << std::quoted(el) << "\n";
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << "FAIL: " << std::quoted(input) << "\n";
        }

        if (f != l) {
            std::cout << "Remaining input: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Success: "A/B AND C/D"
 -- "A"
 -- "B"
 -- "C"
 -- "D"
Success: "A/B"
 -- "A"
 -- "B"
Success: "A/B AND C/D AND E/F"
 -- "A"
 -- "B"
 -- "C"
 -- "D"
 -- "E"
 -- "F"
```

Perhaps you should have included self-contained code, or elaborate on what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Thanks! The error occured due to the space-handlings